# Derivative of kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, differentiation

I read that the derivative of kinetic energy=$F\cdot v$. I tried to differentiate (1/2) mv^2 with respect to time but each time I am getting $m*v$ and not $m*a*v$ which solves to $F*v$.
My efforts are as follows:

[image]

Required URL from where I found it: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_13.html

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the procedure:

$KE = 0.5mv^2$

$\frac{d}{dt}KE = 0.5m\frac{d}{dt}v^2$

So the question becomes,how do we find the derivative of $v^2$ with respect to time?

One can easily see that $\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dt}\frac{d}{dv}$ (Notice how the $dv$ cancels top and bottom)

Therefore,

$\frac{d}{dt}v^2 = \frac{dv}{dt}\frac{d}{dv}v^2 = \frac{dv}{dt}\times 2v$

Therefore,
$\frac{d}{dt}KE = 0.5\times2mv\frac{dv}{dt} = vm\frac{dv}{dt} = vma = Fv$

Comment: @mew-Is this called the chain rule?

Comment: Yes.  The chain rule is the part where d/dt = dv/dt times d/dv

Comment: So is the rate of change of kinetic energy equal to power? But in definition of power is just the change of energy with respect to time.

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas that's right, power is the rate of energy change, so if that's due to change in kinetic energy then power is Fv

Comment: @Kenshin We have two forms of energy or potential. Can power refer to rate of change of potential energy? I am asking this because usually we have power connected to the transformation rate from one form to another or the rate at which work is done (which relates to the change of kinetic energy. So with what definition should we stick, $ P=\frac{dE}{dt}$ or $P=\frac{dW}{dt}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Is this the correct way to find the derivative of kinetic energy?

$$
K=\frac{1}{2}m v^2 \\
$$
So:
$$
\frac{dK}{dt} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{dm}{dt} v^2 + 2mv \frac{dv}{dt} \right)
$$
If the mass does not change over the time, then $$\frac{dm}{dt}=0$$

And finally
$$
\frac{dK}{dt} = \frac{1}{2} \left(2mv \frac{dv}{dt} \right)
$$

So simplifying:
$$
\frac{dK}{dt} = mv \frac{dv}{dt}=mav=F.v 
$$

Comment: Thank for the correction docscience You're right!, K is a scalar

Answer (score 2):

The time derivative of $v^2$ is $2v \frac{dv}{dt}$ not $2v$. You must use the chain rule.

Comment: @mikestone-Can you please show me the steps?

Comment: @soham Its basic calculus. Check chain rule on wikipedia.

Comment: @soham If you check out **any** introductory calculus textbook, surely the chain rule figures prominently. It is an indispensable tool used for differentiating used in nearly all courses in calculus of any level.